# display exception in JTextField

Tags: java, exception, throw

My code does some arithmetic to convert a binary input to decimal output. I also made an exception class that extends NumberFormatException to throw an error if the input is not a 1 or 0. What I want is to throw the exception to a JTextField.

```
    private void biTodeciActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
String binary;
binary = binaryStringText.getText();
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++)
{
    if (binary.charAt(i) != '0' && binary.charAt(i) != '1')
    {
        throw new ParseMethods.BinaryNumberFormatException(binary.charAt(i)+" is not"
                +" a valid binary input.");
    }
    else if(binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
        total += Math.pow(2, (binary.length()-1)-i );
    }
}

deciOut.setText(""+total);
}
```

Comment: You can't `throw` an exception from method which doesn't define it. So you're kind of stuck with it.  In you case, I'd just call `setText` of the text field, passing the information you want to (assuming you want to display the exception within the field) or more practically, use a `JOptionPane` to display the error message

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, what you're trying to do won't work.  The `BinaryNumberFormatException` doesn't declare that it throws any exceptions (and assuming you're using NetBeans), you won't be able to (easily) modify it.

You could wrap all you code in a `try-catch` block within the method, but that's just, well, kind of messy (IMHO)

Instead, what I might do, is create a class which does the conversation, something like...

```
public static class BinaryConverter {
    public static String toDecimal(String binary) throws BinaryNumberFormatException {
        //...
    }

    // Maybe a toBinary method as well...
}
```

for example.  The `toDecimal` declares the fact that it will throw a `BinaryNumberFormatException` (although I think some kind of parse exception would be better)

Then in your action performed method, you could do something like...

```
private void biTodeciActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    try {
        deciOut.setText(BinaryConverter.toDecimal(binaryStringText.getText()));
    } catch (BinaryNumberFormatException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        deciOut.setText(exp.getMessage());
    }
}
```

which would allow to deal with the operation been successful and unsuccessful in a more succinct manner.

This makes the code more reusable and easier to manager.

As an idea

Comment: Well, I do already have the methods for paseBinary which takes a String input and returns an int. But when I try to call it in biTodeciActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) Netbeans tells me it doesn't know about the method. They are both in the default package.

Comment: Without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, it's impossible to know what else is wrong with the code.

Comment: I got it to work. Your answer helped me a lot thanks!

Comment: Glad it could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Print exception directly into textfield in STRING format
deciOut.setText(""+exp);